# Django - Share a selected object model in many apps

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm working on a webinterface  to manage (crud) point cloud and 3d scanning work.

To avoid to mention on which project i m working on, i would like to use something like a cookie that says i m working on object C26 from object B5 from A5. I want to display on which object i m working on an automatically  feed form with the foreign key.

I have 3 apps.

1. app1 : select or create an object A
2. app2 : based on object A (foreign key), i create an object B or select a B object if many are existing.
3. app3 : based on object B (foreign key), i create C

Concretely,

1. App1, i create and manage (crud) a geolocation (geodjango object : point)
2. App2, i create and manage (crud) a station (similar to geolocation)
3. App3, i create and manage (crud) a scanning instance for pointcloud (pointclouds)

Which is the best tool to do that and how to?

- signal
- middleware
- context
- url with parameter

something else?

https://github.com/jlstanus/ocm_django

**EDIT_1**: OK, session is the feature i need. If i want the session context to be displayed in the base.html template without to check it in each view. Shouldn't I add the *request.session['place']* in a middleware?

Comment: Why not store it in the session? That's exactly what it's for.

Comment: You can add this as an answer: self.resquest.session in generic views or resquest.session